# Alternate API hits are getting failed in WSO2 API Manager. Any suggestion?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I've tried hitting an API, alternate hits are getting failed and showing as connection timeout.

In logs I've found this.

WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0

Database: Mysql
Environment: Distributed Environment

```
ERROR {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState} -  Unable to reset autocommit state to connection. {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState}
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 936,547 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 936,550 milliseconds ago.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:2054)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.reset(ConnectionState.java:91)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.setupConnection(ConnectionPool.java:327)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:201)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCLogsDAO.beginTransaction(JDBCLogsDAO.java:325)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCLogsDAO.getLogList(JDBCLogsDAO.java:296)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.getLogs(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2389)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.getLogs(CacheBackedRegistry.java:485)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogsInternal(UserRegistry.java:1810)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$3600(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1781)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1778)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogs(UserRegistry.java:1778)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.submitResource(ResourceSubmitter.java:119)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.run(ResourceSubmitter.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

registry.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!--
  ~ Copyright 2005-2011 WSO2, Inc. (http://wso2.com)
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->
<wso2registry>
    <!-- 
    For details on configuring different config & governance registries see;
    http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances
    -->

    <currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>

    <dbConfig name="wso2registry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>

    <!-- This handler provides the feature to add a simlink to a given resource -->

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.ExtensionsSymLinkHandler">
        <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.URLMatcher">
            <property name="pattern">.*</property>
        </filter>
    </handler>

    <!-- This handler provides resource retention locking for the resources -->

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.RetentionHandler" 
            methods="PUT,DELETE,MOVE,RENAME,IMPORT,COPY,ADD_ASSOCIATION,REMOVE_ASSOCIATION,RESTORE,RESTORE_VERSION">
        <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.URLMatcher">
            <property name="pattern">.*</property>
        </filter>
    </handler>

    <!-- This handler processes the services being added to the registry -->

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.ServiceMediaTypeHandler">
        <!--property name="disableWSDLValidation">true</property-->
        <property name="defaultServiceVersion">1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</property>
        <property name="disableSymlinkCreation">true</property>
        <property name="smartLifecycleLinks" type="xml">
            <key>dev</key>
            <key>qa</key>
            <key>live</key>
        </property>        
        <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.MediaTypeMatcher">
            <property name="mediaType">application/vnd.wso2-service+xml</property>
        </filter>
    </handler>

    <!-- This handler provides the ability to remove the entire heirarchy for a given service while deleting the service -->

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.DeleteHierarchyHandler">
        <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.MediaTypeMatcher">
            <property name="mediaType">application/vnd.wso2-service+xml</property>
        </filter>
    </handler>    


    <!-- This handler use to index APIs when there change in Api artifact-->
    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.IndexingHandler">
        <filter class = "org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.MediaTypeMatcher">
            <property name="mediaType">application/vnd.wso2-api+xml</property>
        </filter>
    </handler>

   <!--This handler delete the subscription hierarcy generated in the notifications path when a subscription is deleted directly -->

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.DeleteHierarchyHandler">
         <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.URLMatcher">
                <property name="deletePattern">/_system/governance/event/topics/registry/notifications/.*</property>
         </filter>
    </handler>


    <!-- This handler processes the links for the lifecycle -->

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.SmartLifecycleLinkHandler">
        <property name="states" type="xml">
            <state key="dev">Created</state>
            <state key="qa">Tested</state>
            <state key="live">Deployed</state>
        </property>
        <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.MediaTypeMatcher">
            <property name="mediaType">application/vnd.wso2-smart-link</property>
        </filter>
    </handler>

    <!-- This handler processes the policy files of the given media type defined by the filter -->

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.PolicyMediaTypeHandler">
    <property name="policyLocationConfiguration" type="xml">
            <location>/trunk/policies/</location>            
    </property>
        <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.MediaTypeMatcher">
            <property name="mediaType">application/policy+xml</property>
        </filter>
    </handler>

    <!-- This handler processes the schema types which are defined by the filter  -->

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.XSDMediaTypeHandler">
        <!--property name="disableSchemaValidation">true</property-->
        <property name="disableSymlinkCreation">true</property>
        <property name="locationConfiguration" type="xml">
            <location>/trunk/schemas/</location>            
        </property>
        <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.MediaTypeMatcher">
            <property name="mediaType">application/x-xsd+xml</property>
        </filter>
    </handler>

    <!-- This handler processes making an external link to a given resource -->

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.ExternalLinkHandler">
        <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.MediaTypeMatcher">
            <property name="mediaType">application/vnd.wso2-hyperlink</property>
        </filter>
    </handler>

    <!-- This handler processes service end-points defined in the WSDL files being uploaded to the registry -->

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.EndpointMediaTypeHandler">
        <property name="endpointMediaType">application/vnd.wso2.endpoint</property>
        <property name="endpointLocationConfiguration" type="xml">
            <location>/trunk/endpoints/</location>
        </property>
        <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.filters.EndpointMediaTypeMatcher">
        </filter>
    </handler>

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.handlers.UriMediaTypeHandler">
    <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.MediaTypeMatcher">
        <property name="mediaType">application/vnd.wso2-uri+xml</property>
    </filter>
    </handler>

    <!-- When a resource/governance artifact is deleted, this handler will cleanup all its bounded subscriptions from registry-->

    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.DeleteSubscriptionHandler">
         <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.URLMatcher">
                 <property name="pattern">.*</property>
         </filter>
    </handler>

    <!--This handler manage the meta data resource caching-->
    <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.handlers.MetaDataCacheHandler">
        <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.URLMatcher">
            <property name="pattern">.*</property>
        </filter>
    </handler>

    <!--This handler clears the caches when workflow-extension config is updated.-->
   <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.handlers.APIConfigMediaTypeHandler" methods="PUT,DELETE">
      <filter class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.filters.MediaTypeMatcher">
        <property name="mediaType">workflow-config</property>
    </filter>
   </handler>


    <indexingConfiguration>
        <startIndexing>false</startIndexing>
        <skipCache>true</skipCache>
        <startingDelayInSeconds>35</startingDelayInSeconds>
        <indexingFrequencyInSeconds>3</indexingFrequencyInSeconds>
        <!--number of resources submit for given indexing thread -->
        <batchSize>40</batchSize>
        <!--number of worker threads for indexing -->
        <indexerPoolSize>40</indexerPoolSize>
        <!-- location storing the time the indexing took place-->
        <lastAccessTimeLocation>/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime</lastAccessTimeLocation>
        <!-- the indexers that implement the indexer interface for a relevant media type/(s) -->
        <indexers>

            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.indexers.RXTIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/vnd.(.)+\+xml" profiles ="default,api-store,api-publisher"/>

        <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.indexing.indexer.PlainTextIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="text/plain+" profiles ="default,api-store,api-publisher"/>
        <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.indexing.indexer.PDFIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/pdf" profiles ="default,api-store,api-publisher"/>
        <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.indexing.indexer.MSWordIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/msword" profiles ="default,api-store,api-publisher"/>
        <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.indexing.indexer.MSPowerpointIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" profiles ="default,api-store,api-publisher"/>
        <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.indexing.indexer.MSExcelIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/vnd.ms-excel" profiles ="default,api-store,api-publisher"/>
        <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.indexing.indexer.XMLIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/xml" profiles ="default,api-store,api-publisher"/>
            <indexer class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.indexing.indexer.WSDLIndexer" mediaTypeRegEx="application/api-wsdl" profiles ="default,api-store,api-publisher"/>
        </indexers>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion pathRegEx="/_system/config/repository/dashboards/gadgets/swfobject1-5/.*[.]html"/>
            <exclusion pathRegEx="/_system/local/repository/components/org[.]wso2[.]carbon[.]registry/mount/.*"/>
        </exclusions>
    </indexingConfiguration>


    <versionResourcesOnChange>false</versionResourcesOnChange>

    <!-- NOTE: You can edit the options under "StaticConfiguration" only before the
     startup. -->
    <staticConfiguration>
        <versioningProperties>true</versioningProperties>
        <versioningComments>true</versioningComments>
        <versioningTags>true</versioningTags>
        <versioningRatings>true</versioningRatings>
        <!-- Location you want to add service and default location will be /services/ -->
        <servicePath>/trunk/services/</servicePath>
    </staticConfiguration>

    <!-- This enables auto-versioning of resources (non-collection). Whenever a resource is updated a new version will be created -->

    <versionResourcesOnChange>false</versionResourcesOnChange>

    <!-- This enables JMX management for G-Reg -->

    <jmx enabled="false">
        <service name="InvocationStatistics" enabled="true"/>
        <service name="Activities" enabled="true"/>
        <service name="Properties" enabled="true"/>
        <service name="Subscriptions" enabled="true"/>
        <service name="Events" enabled="true"/>
    </jmx>



</wso2registry>
```

In gateway node,  value is set to false. But still we are facing the issue 
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Seems like there is a connection error with the mysql server. Could you please verify the mysql server is running and reachable to this node?

Comment: It doesn't seem the error is related to the request failure. (1) Are you sure you get this error for every request failure? (2) in which node do you see this error?

Comment: @Bee, In API gateway node wso2 carbon log I can find this error. We are facing this issue intermediately and mysql connection looks fine

Comment: @Menaka Mysql connection is looking fine

Comment: Can you share the datasources? Check if autoReconnect is set to true in the JDBC URL.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to `indexing`, and can't be related to API calls. And the gateway node does not need indexing. Let's try disabling indexing.

Open `repository/conf/registry.xml` and set the value of `<startIndexing>` to `false`. Then restart.

Comment: In gateway node, <startIndexing> value is set to false. But still we are facing the issue

Comment: any help, please?

Comment: Can you confirm the version is 2.6.0? Did you restart after the change? And please attach the registry.xml

Comment: Yes we are on RHEL 7 and APIM 2.6.0. We did restart after config change but still the same issue persists. Added registry.xml to the question itself. Please have a look.